# Using a variable in multiple Cpp files

Tags: c++, scope, arduino, header-files, atmelstudio

I am working with an Arduino project in Atmel studios. I need to declare, initialize and use an int in one section of code (settings.cpp/settings.h) and also use it in another .cpp file (error.cpp). I was wondering what the best way to do this is.

My plan was to declare the int as an extern int in settings.h, initialize it in settings.cpp and then #include settings.h in error.cpp.

I'm just wondering if this is the best way to best way to do this or do I need to consider anything when giving error.cpp access to settings.h

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to define it private in settings.h and initialize it in settings.cpp.

Then you can use a `int getVar()` and `void setVar(int)` which you declare as public functions in settings.h and implement in settings.cpp.

From your error class, you include `settings.h` and you can call these functions. This approach is more work, but it tends to be safer, since you have more control on what happens with your variable.

Comment: Hi Dr, I actually did it this way originally but still have to include settings.h in my error.cpp to access the functions. My real question is if there is any adverse effects to including settings.h in error.cpp. and if there was anyway to do it without using and include

Comment: There should be no side effects of including settings.h in error.cpp. And why would you want to do it without include?

Comment: I don't know why but I had it in my head that I should only give access when completely necessary and limit access whenever possible. I have been working a lot with classes and inheritance lately and think I just have my wires crossed trying to limit access. Thanks for the answer, I will go ahead and use the include confidently :)

Answer (score 1):

In a `.h` (header) file, define:

```
extern int myvar;
```

Then use it everywhere in the global scope.

Comment: Hi Quantum, I actually need to use it inside a function in the error.cpp. If I don't #include settings.h I get an error saying that my int "was not declared in this scope" Is it ok to include settings.h or is that an issue.

Comment: Why not include `settings.h` there? If errors depend on settings, then there's no way around it.

Comment: I don't know why but I had it in my head that I should only give access when completely necessary and limit access whenever possible. I have been working a lot with classes and inheritance lately and think I just have my wires crossed trying to limit access. Thanks for the answer quantun

Comment: It's true that you have to give only access to what is necessary, but errors depend on something from settings. Then that decides it!